# Autowire fails after moving spring context to META-INF

Tags: java, spring, autowired, meta-inf

After moving my spring context configuration into `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring` I am not able to wire my beans. Before my spring context was placed directly under the src folder and my tests as well as autowiring runs fine:

[image]

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:cmn-dao-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class ComplaintDaoTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private ComplaintDao mComplaintDao;
```

Error:

```
09.12.2013 23:30:02 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SCHWERWIEGEND: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@873723] to prepare test instance [null(de.bc.qz.dao.ComplaintDaoTest)]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'de.bc.qz.dao.ComplaintDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.bc.qz.dao.ComplaintDao de.bc.qz.dao.ComplaintDaoTest.mComplaintDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [de.bc.qz.dao.ComplaintDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
```

database.properties:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: in run configurations for the test under classpath are you sure that directory is being added?

Comment: I thought it should be enough to add the annotation ContextConfiguration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `classpath*:META-INF/spring/cmn-dao-context.xml`

**EDIT**

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>META-INF/spring/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: it fails with the same message if I try: @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/cmn-dao-context.xml" })

Comment: also with @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/cmn-dao-context.xml" })

Comment: I think I did something wrong by creating the new structure src/main/resources
I created those directorys via create new src-directories. META-INF/spring are standard file directories.

Comment: Put your META-INF in your main src directory

Comment: try with classpath*:META-INF/spring/cmn-dao-context.xml. I did not see that you had the spring folder under META-INF

Comment: thx after putting the directory directly under src it seems to work. unfortunality I get now that exception:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
But the database.properties is placed in the same directory...

Comment: Do the same thing with the location property. Check the update.

Comment: yeaaaa. changed it to META-INF/spring/database.properties and works very well! +1 and accepted thx a lot